# Как из json получать данные с разных уровней?

Tags: javascript, json

Как из JSON файла получать данные второго уровня? Вот например с первым уровнем понятно ' + data.id + ', а как вывести данные из параметра comment? Пробовал ' + data.commen.id + ', но не работает. Как еще можно это сделать? или как указать в скрипте на них?

```
{
    "id": "7",
    "foto": "/images/content/avatar-review.jpg",
    "name": "Rosa",
    "text": "Mein Traum ist wahr geworden, ich bin eine Königin! Seit Langem hat mir dieses Modell gefallen, ein sehr schöner Ring. Die Feinheit der Krone macht den Ring zu einem besonderen Prestigeobjekt. Ich war schon beim ersten Anprobieren ganz hingerissen.",
    "star": "1",
    "date": "22.10.2015 17:17",
    "comment": [{
        "id": "8",
        "foto": "/images/content/avatar-review.jpg",
        "name": "Rosa",
        "text": "Mein Traum ist wahr geworden, ich bin eine Königin! Seit Langem hat mir dieses Modell gefallen, ein sehr schöner Ring. Die Feinheit der Krone macht den Ring zu einem besonderen Prestigeobjekt. Ich war schon beim ersten Anprobieren ganz hingerissen.",
        "date": "22.10.2015 17:17"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это массив в квадратных скобках, его нулевой элемент - объект, выводите так:

`data.comment[0]['id']`

Comment: это добавляется в скрипт? точнее как правильно его в скрипте добавить?

Comment: @drtvader вы про что спрашивали? - "Как из JSON файла получать данные второго уровня? " Я вам ответил как получать данные с того самого второго уровня.

Comment: а что значит "o" перед точкой? Сильно не пинайтесь, это просто мой 2 скрипт без особых знаний JS.

Comment: @drtvader это ваш объект, исправил на `data`